# How can I read if theres any activity on the serialport?

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, arduino-uno

I have a PIR-sensor and a controller hooked up to my USB, and I can read in the Terminal the controllers output if there is any motion using `serial.readline()`.

But what I really want to do is just check if there is any activity on the port (meaning there is motion detected).

Somthing like;

```
if(serial.readline() == true)
    //do something
```

or maybe:

```
if(serial.readline() != null)
    //do something
```

Can someone help me out with this, or at least point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Given your use case, an option would be to perform non-blocking read by creating the connection with a time-out of 0 (see http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html)

```
my_serial = serial.Serial(..., timeout = 0)
```

That way, you will have non-blocking `read`.

That being said, by doing so, you might end up by regularly pooling the serial port for incoming data. Depending the application this might be acceptable or not.

Depending your OS, with non-blocking serial connection, you might probably use [select](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select) or [poll](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.poll) to check for data availability.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will definitely look in to this